# python win32 extensions documentation

Tags: python, documentation, pywin32

I'm new to both python and the python win32 extensions available at http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/ but I can't find any documentation online or in the installation directories concerning what exactly the win32 extensions provide. Where is this information?

Comment: Their documentations suck. Quick solution is just go directly to venv/Lib/site-packages/win32 and look at the code. The comments are quite descriptive and they have demos too.

Comment: IT'S NOT OFF-TOPIC!!!
PLEASE DO NOT CLOSE QUESTIONS UNLESS THEY HAVE NOTHING TO DO WITH PROGRAMMING! Learn to think beyond yourselves! There may be a lot of people who have the question you are closing and cannot find an answer otherwise searching in the Web. The present question is a perfect example of such a case!

Comment: Question https://stackoverflow.com/q/5481686/1099571 is a duplicate of this, and it has good answers, and it was not closed for being off-topic. (BTW voters to close, I don't understand why this question is out of scope; your decision to close would be clearer if you pointed out which out-of-scope rule it violates. I can make a case that it satisfies rules for what is in-scope.)

Comment: The raging screaming caps was obviously unnecessary, but no, this question shouldn't have been closed.  This isn't a question for "recommendations" at all, he was asking where the official docs for a library are.  Some people just like to mash the "vote to close" button for fun.

Answer (score 13):

You'll find documentation here:
http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyWin32.HTML

(Note: most of the API docs are under 'modules' and 'objects'. Note that the documentation is very sparse here but rembember: since it's only a wrapper on top of the win32 API --> the 'full' documentation is also on the MSDN website, google should be helpful...)

Comment: Those are 2.4 docs; the latest one (for 2.6) is available at http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/PyWin32.HTML

Comment: The lastest Version of documentation is [ActiveState doc python 3.3](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32api.html)

Comment: When I click on Python for Win32 Extensions Site (http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond) I get a "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /crew/mhammond on this server." error

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ChristopheD's recommendations I also find that [Tim Golden's Python Stuff](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/index.html) is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Python Programming On Win32](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926219) from O'Reilly is a great, if dated, book on the subject. I've read it and is very good.

[image: You can get it in Amazon too.]

Its not documentation, *per se*, but its really useful for a good introduction to COM programming with Python, among other advanced stuff.

Comment: For example: http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html

Answer (score 2):

PyWin32 docs are included with [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/) (which I highly recommend you to install). ChristopheD's link is for Python 2.4 which is an older version. For Python 2.6 version (which is the latest), [here is the CHM file](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/etc/ActivePython26.chm) that contains PyWin32 docs. Note that this CHM file is also included with ActivePython itself.

[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/87045/permalinks/apy26-pywin32.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/87045/permalinks/apy26-pywin32.png)

Comment: Please send us the CHM file back. URL is broken where can we read A to Z of PyWin32 or win32ui plz?