# Why can't I find any pywin32 documentation/resources

Tags: python, pywin32, pywin

I cannot find pywin32 documentation or even a little synopsis of what the module is (I am aware its for win32 API stuff).

Is there any pywin32 documentation or resources? Maybe some examples?

Comment: It's probably best to remove the 'why' from this question.  "Why' is not what you wanted answered; 'Where can I find' is ;-)

Comment: Additional info: If you want to manipulate Office applications with pywin32, be sure to check out the Object Browsers in different Office applications, so that you know the properties and methods of each object.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The PyWin32 installation includes a `.chm` help file at `[Pythonpath]\Lib\site-packages\PyWin32.chm`.

The same info is online at http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/index.html

ActiveState used to keep this documentation online as well, including listings of modules and objects, but that seems to be taken offline.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, DDE is not actually documented, anywhere
http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/dde.html

The **doc** strings are all empty:

```
    >>> dde.CreateServer.__doc__
    >>>
```